# Is it possible to attach standard actions like 'Sharing' and 'Change Owner' to custom buttons when creating a custom Record Page in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, record, navigation, action

Is it possible to attach standard actions like 'Sharing' and 'Change Owner' to custom buttons when creating a custom Record Page in LWC? For 'edit' and 'clone' I'm using NavigationMixin, but what can be using for 'Sharing' and 'Change Owner'?

Comment: As of now only, edit, clone, and view are supported for record page navigation mixins. check the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type)

Comment: okey, thank you